# need help in adding Alexa Certify Code in head section

Tags: component, plugin

I am trying to add Alexa Certify Code in head section in template but code appear in frontend and i also use the System - OpenPotion Head and Body plugin but same, and Google Analytics codes in body section also same.

I am using the gk_news template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the code directly in the template file:

- Open the file `/templates/gk_news/layouts/default.php`
- Go to line # 63 (aproximately) and find the `</head>` tag.
- Add your code just before the `</head>` tag:
- Save the file.

Your file should look something like this:

```
...
<jdoc:include type="head" />
<?php $this->layout->loadBlock('head'); ?>
<?php $this->layout->loadBlock('cookielaw'); ?>
<!-- ADD YOUR CODE HERE -->
</head>
```

Comment: thanks for reply, i am adding in same area but after i can see all cords in front-end top of the page.

Comment: Are you sure the code is correct? There might be an error or a missing tag. Can you add the code (or parts of it) to your question?

Comment: yes cords is correct, even if i add Google analytics cords in body section also same happen, and i have try with other template that also same.

Comment: i have added the cords above in my Question

Comment: OK, let's do a small test. Please remove any code you've added to your template, and add this right before the `</head>` tag:
`<script>window.onload = function () { alert("This message is coming from the head tag.") }</script>`. Do you see the message when you load your website? Is the code visible on the page after you click OK?

Comment: i can see this cords in front-end page loading.   window.on-load = function () { alert("This message is coming from the head tag.") }

Comment: Sounds like you're doing something wrong when adding your code. I tried your code on several GK templates, and it works fine. Are you sure you're adding the code in the correct location (see my example). How are you adding your code to the `default.php` file (text-editor, Joomla template editor or maybe cPanel code editor...)?

Comment: i am using Joomla template editor

Comment: thank you very much Dear, it is done already. your right i was doing wrong it was problem with using Joomla template editor.